# Better name needed for applying a function on elements of a container

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have a container class (containing a multi-index container) for which I have a public "foreach" member-function, so users can pass a functor to apply on all elements.
While implementing, I had a case where the functor should only be applied to some elements of a range in the container, so I overloaded the foreach, to pass some valid range.
Now, in some cases, it was worthwhile to stop on a certain condition, so practically, I let the foreach stop based on the return-value of the function.

I'm pleased with how the system works, but I have one concern:
**How should a "foreach" on a range, with stop conditions be called?**
Anyone knows a generic, clear and concise name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description, i'd go for `apply_until()`.

Comment: I like the apply_... name because it shows that it is an interface to apply functions.  Strangely enough, I put it in the the title, but it hasn't crossed my mind to actually use it as a function name.  I guess, foreach was stuck too much in my head.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `until` or something?

Answer (score 1):

How about `find_if(...)`, as in stl ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call it either `foreach_until` or `foreach_while` (attempting to follow a convention based on the `_if` functions like `replace_if` and `remove_if`, except that the condition here isn't "if" each one is true, it's "until" the end condition holds). Or just `foreach`. `std::for_each` ignores the return value of the functor, but that doesn't necessarily mean that your function called `foreach` has to. I think it's a pretty common idiom for a callback function to have a return value allowing early exit from the controlling loop.

If the callback returns either a false value (to continue) or a true value (to halt), then you could call the function `find_if`. That's basically what it is, and it could be implemented using `std::find_if`, even if the caller isn't interested in which iterator provoked the end condition.

Comment: I am intrigued by the find_if, because it is answered twice.  I thought that "find..."-functions are about returning members and that "..._if" functions used "predicates" as in "pure functions that return a boolean based on some condition".  Am I being too strict?

Comment: Predicates return a value "testable as true", not necessarily a boolean. They aren't required to be pure, but they must not call non-const functions on their parameter: I neglected to mention that as a condition. All in 25/7. You're right that `find` functions are about returning the iterator that triggered the "stop", but you can always ignore a return value. Really I just mean that if `find_if` is "close enough" to what you want, then use it even if conceptually you aren't finding anything. If it's not "close enough", don't use that name :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide a subset function that returns a view of the elements of interest, maybe you don't need apply_until().  Just `myContainer.subset(3, 17).foreach(myFunctor)`  I think that's a better separation of concerns.

Comment: Wow, a sort of different approach.  It sounds nice.  Practically for me, it would mean having another class (the subset) with access to the internal container, though.

Comment: On second thought, it would only need 2 iterators, so I should keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

a generic name? ConditionalIterator? RangeIterator? Or since it's a function, perhaps IterateRange?